# azure adf mapping data flow expression with case statement on cached sink

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

I am using Azure Data Factory Mapping Data Flows.

I am trying to write an equivalent of sql 'case' statement to get a value in a derived column based on cashed sink.

My cashed sink input is a query: 'select ID from dbo.aaa'. It returns all ID as Integers, they are visible in 'Data Preview'.

My derived column expression is:

iif(contains(chachedIDs#, #item==ID), "upserted row", "deleted row").

The above must be wrong as I cannot preview, ADF says: 'Type mismatch'. 'Expression type could not be evaluated, correct the expression'
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use sink cache in dataflow expression, you need to use [`Cached lookup functions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-cached-lookup-functions#cached-lookup-function-list).

Use the below expression in the derived column to achieve your requirement.

```
iif(contains(sink1#outputs(),#item.ID== ID),'upserted row','deleted row')
```

**My cached lookup output:**

[image]

Use the above expression and this is my result.

[image]

While transforming these data to any other sink file, make sure you give correct sink ordering in settings.

[image]